# Where's all this light coming from?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built an underground mob spawner in 1.8 SMP that I can turn the lights on and off in. I used pistons to move glowstone over glass holes in the ceiling - whenever the lights are off the holes are covered.

But...there's light coming in from somewhere! The rest of the room is solid cobble or smooth stone, so I can't figure out why there would be so much light! How can I seal the room in darkness?

[image]

Different angle:

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing there is lava down those shafts to kill the monsters? That generates light.

Comment: What happens when you place a block somewhere near the brightest spot of one of the lit area, and then break it? It might be a bug where the lighting doesn't update.

Comment: @agf No, the mobs are going to go to the surface before I killses them. I'm looking around for lava outside though, like Raven Dreamer suggested.

Comment: @KevinY: Looks like that may be it. I placed and broke blocks with the lights off, and it got dark. However when I cycled the lights they were lit up again. Apparently there are still [lighting bugs](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Known_bugs#Lighting), so maybe I hit one of them. Do you happen to know of a workaround? Otherwise I may just darken it and forget about the lighting system for now.

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I don't know of any workarounds. Hopefully it'll be fixed in 1.9.

Answer (score 8):

I saw this bug in some version of 1.8, I think (but in the form of torches placed underwater leaving light behind). I didn't find any way to fix it.

It's fixed in a 1.9 prerelease.

Answer (score 3):

Is there possibly lava nearby?

In my experience, light from lava ignores line of sight -- at least as of 1.8.

Comment: I'll have to look around a bit. There may be one that I didn't kill when exploring the caves around.

Comment: @Michael Just explore directly towards the apparent source of the light!

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this before. Kevin Y is correct. It is a lighting glitch which should be (and for me always has been) fixed by placing a few blocks in the brightest area and breaking them.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize you had already discovered that. In regards to it coming back, how bad would it be if you just left a few blocks in the brightest area?