# Water "retaining" light?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where's all this light coming from?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/wheres-all-this-light-coming-from)

My very simple hostile mob spawner has a slight problem. The problem being that the mob spawner doesn't spawn mobs. The basic idea was to have a huge cobblestone box, in which mobs would spawn, fall into a central hole (with the help of water, and then be killed at the bottom.

However, I can't seem to get rid of this strange light in the spawner. There are no torches around; I have checked thoroughly. In fact, the light seems to be coming from the water source blocks. The odd thing is, whenever I force one of the water blocks to update, the light goes away, but when I close up the box and open it again, the water starts glowing again. In any case, nothing spawns.[image: Light-up water‽]

Comment: Possibly related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/wheres-all-this-light-coming-from

Comment: @Resorath That question didn't seem to explain _why_ it was happening. In addition, that applied to light sources _in_ the water, of which I assure you I had none. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](http://minecraftupdate.com/minecraft-beta-1-8/)¹ in Beta 1.8 which was [reportedly fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/31967/1980) in the Beta 1.9 prereleases prior to the official release.

¹ Apologies for the non-official source; I'm at work and can't access [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Known_bugs) to see which page it's listed on.

Comment: Minecraft Wiki is not especially “official” — it just has lots of people editing it. I say this as one of those editors: Don't assume it's correct.

Comment: @Kevin Reid — Jeb is known to work from the wiki's bug list, which I'd say makes it closer to official than anything else we've got. :-)